# Different behavior between content-type image and pdf

Tags: php, content-type

I got a problem with header content-type in PHP. Lets me explain.

I try to return image and PDF file to an angular V7 app.

This code for the image works fine:

```
$im = file_get_contents($image_file_name);
header('content-type: image/png');
echo $im;
```

I get well the blob in angular. But if I test that for my pdf file :

```
$im = file_get_contents($pdf_file_name);
header('content-type: application/pdf');
echo $im;
```

In Postman, the PDF file works well and I can download it. Even in Chrome console, I can see well the blob of the PDF but at the end, I got an error : "Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Core\App::run() must be an instance of Core\Response, null returned ". This error is due to my architecture because I wait for a instance of Response but the architecture is the same between image and pdf so I don't understand why the first one works but not the second. In the first case, the Response is set after with the echo, but not in the second one...
But if I test that :

```
$im = file_get_contents($pdf_file_name);
header('content-type: image/png');
echo $im;
```

I didn't get the error (but the file is of course not displayed because of the header content-type). But the Response is well set. Any ideas ?

This is my App file :

```
/**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function run(Request $request): Response
    {
        if (0 === strpos($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'application/json')) {
            $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
            $request->request->replace(is_array($data) ? $data : array());
        }

        $method = $request->getMethod();

        if ($method === 'OPTIONS') {
            return new Response(json_encode([]));
        }

        $uri = $request->getRequestUri();

        // Strip query string (?foo=bar) and decode URI
        if (false !== $pos = strpos($uri, '?')) {
            $uri = substr($uri, 0, $pos);
        }
        $uri = rawurldecode($uri);
        if (isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_BASE'])) {
            $uri = str_replace($_SERVER['REDIRECT_BASE'], '', $uri);
        }

        $routeInfo = $this->dispatcher->dispatch($method, $uri);

        try {
            switch ($routeInfo[0]) {
                case FastRoute\Dispatcher::NOT_FOUND:
                    throw new HttpNotFoundException('404 Not Found');
                    break;
                case FastRoute\Dispatcher::METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED:
                    $allowedMethods = $routeInfo[1];
                    throw new HttpForbiddenException('Method not allowed : ' . prettyArray($allowedMethods));
                    break;
                case FastRoute\Dispatcher::FOUND:
                    $handler = $routeInfo[1];
                    AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists');

                    if (isset($this->requestInterceptor)) {
                        return $this->requestInterceptor->handleRequest($request, $routeInfo);
                    }

                    $vars = $routeInfo[2];
                    //var_dump($vars);
                    $response = null;
                    if (count($vars) > 0) {
                        $args = [];
                        foreach ($vars as $k => $v) {
                            $args[] = $v;
                        }
                        $args[] = $request;

                        $response = call_user_func_array($handler, $args);
                    } else {
                        $response = call_user_func($handler, $request);
                    }

                    return $response;
                    break;
            }
        } catch (QueryException $e) {
            return new Response(json_encode($e->getTrace()));
        } catch (HttpExceptionInterface $e) {
            return $e->asResponse();
        }

//        return new Response();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You're not using plain PHP, aren't you? Because your code doesn't throw an error on my machine using `PHP 5.6.38-0+deb8u1`.

Comment: I think it's because you have not my architecture. In my case, it is use in an api. In my case the pop blob is well shown in the console of chrome but with the error I said at the end.

Comment: You just gave us this little of PHP code. How are we supposed to know your architecture? With plain PHP, your code works. If it doesn't due to your "architecture" (I'd rather call id framework then ...) - that's on your side and we cannot help you with that because we don't know anything about it.

Comment: The architecture is not the the real problem there because it is the same in the both case. It works with image header, but not with PDF header...

Comment: If you really believe that, good luck!

Comment: There's nothing being `return`ed here at all, so obviously the code you've shown us isn't causing the problem. We have no idea what `Core\App` is.

Comment: OK my bad. I edited the content with my App file.